# How to see what tracks I've sent to friends in Spotify?

Tags: music, spotify

I have a Spotify premium account. One of my favorite things about the service is the ease of sharing music with friends. But it doesn't appear there is a way to see all the music I've dragged and dropped on my friends.

Am I not looking in the right place? Where's my 'historic outbox'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Spotify's latest major update (from several months ago) you can now see the history of your sent and received music in "Messages" in the left panel.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'sent' messages list in Spotify.

Therefore I'm using a normal playlist, that I share with the person I am sending songs to. As it is always in sync, it works quite well, only you don't see notifications of incoming songs.

Maybe there's a thread on Getsatisfaction where you could vote to get the 'sent' messages list feature?
http://getsatisfaction.com/spotify